# Does low predicted variable significance indicate a model problem?

Tags: predictive-models, stata, linear

Suppose I am trying to construct a temporal model of some variable of interest. Suppose I have the following situation, where voi is a variable of interest, t is time, and x is some other variable:

1. `reg voi t` is insignificant
2. `reg voi x` is significant
3. `reg voi log(x)` is significant
4. `reg log(x) log(t)` is significant
5. `reg log(voi) log(t)` is insignificant

Because the direct relation of time on voi is insignificant, but each step of an indirect relation is significant, I decide to construct an indirect model:

1. (Again, so I can predict) `reg log(x) log(t)`
2. `predict predictedlogx`
3. `reg voi predictedlogx`

This significance of the coefficient on predictedlogx here is extremely insignificant. It is slightly better than in the case of `reg voi t`, with a p-value of .811 instead of .813.

How can we explain the fact that each step is significant, but the overall model is insignificant? Is there a better way to go about modelling the relation between voi and t?

Comment: possibly related: https://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2011-01/msg00583.html

Comment: possibly related: https://www.stata.com/features/overview/nonlinear-regression/

Comment: Ended up finding a significant temporal relation using `nl exp2: voi t`. Leaving the question open for a couple days in case a better approach is recommended.